# How to match string between two tokens without the tokens

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a paragraph that I would like to extract strings from that are surrounded by double square brackets `"[[" ... "]]"`. There are some strings within the brackets that contain a bar | and I would like to omit those. I have created the following regex `\[\[([^|]+?)\]\]/g` this regex works flawlessly however it returns the string with the surrounding square brackets. There are similar questions that solve this by using str.split but I match upwards of 200+ strings and it would probably curtail performance, therefore I would only like regex only answers.

*edit* - Forgot to mention that this is a very long paragraph and I need all of the matches therefore I specify the /g flag to obtain an array of all the matches.

Comment: Before you go to optimization, measure the solution with 1000 strings. If it's slow, start thinking of optimizations - till then, find something better to do :-)

Comment: JS doesn't have lookbehinds. Maybe a capture group?

Comment: Your regex works for me. Please show the JS you are using with your regex. How the results come back depends on which regex method you use and whether you specify the "g" flag.

Comment: I don't get it. Just ran your regex in console `/\[\[([^|]+?)\]\]/.exec("[[1]]")[1]` and there're no brackets in result.

Comment: I forgot to make it clear that I have a very long paragraph and I obtain an array with multiple matches.

Comment: @naughtyboy have updated my answer to handle multiple matches

Answer (score 4):

Your regex looks fine. I think you are just looking at the wrong part of the result. When you get a match, [`Regex.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns an array. Index 0 contains the full match, e.g. `"[[value]]"`, and the later indices contains each sub-match within parantheses, e.g. `"value"`. So just look at `match[1]` instead of `match[0]`.

To handle multiple matches, add the `g` flag, and use a `while` loop to run `Regex.exec()` multiple times - this will return a result array for each successive match until no more matches are found and it returns `null`. You can just push each result into an array. Your regex remains the same tho.

```js
var inputs = [
  "foo [[value]] bar",
  "foo [[val1|val2]] bar",
  "foo [[value1]] bar [[value|2]] fizz [[value3]] buzz",
];

console.clear();
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

  var re = /\[\[([^|]+?)\]\]/g;
  var match;
  var matches = [];
  while((match = re.exec(inputs[i])) !== null) {
      matches.push(match[1]);
  }

  console.log(inputs[i]);
  console.log(matches);
}
```